# Very high CPU load on HP Pavillon DV6 2106

Tags: 16.04, intel, cpu-load

I have HP Pavillon DV6 2106 model. It has an Intel core i7 cpu. When I install ubuntu, the cpu load is very high and it feels like it's about to melt.
How can I cope with this problem?

Comment: Do you have an idea why the cpu load is so high or are you just hearing the fans spin at maximum and believe, that therefore the cpu load must be high?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: The question is probably about the CPU FAN, not the CPU LOAD.

Comment: @Pilot6. I just hear the fan with the max spin which produces loud noise

Comment: Set to a maximum frequency on the CPU or set the governor to Performance

Comment: Did you try to save notebook power by installing powersaver package?